# How to resolve member addresses of IL code during runtime

Tags: .net, cil, malware

I am currently investigating a protected .NET malware.

I am working on a PE file that is using the same kind of protection.
It decrypts its IL code during runtime.
I know a piece of the true IL code.

I was able to recover a piece of the same IL code at two different moment.
[picture of the 3 versions of the IL code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qI9m.png)

The first line is the first version of the IL code in memory.

The second line, just before the compileMethod

The last line is what I am supposed to get eventually.

I would like to understand how the evasion works. Why is possible to compile the IL with 0x0A800005 instead of 0x0A00001D (Systems.Windows.Form.Label) and still having a running program.

Is there a way to resolve 0x0A800005 during runtime and understand it is somehow associated with Systems.Windows.Form.Label ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: 0x0AXXXXXX are MemberRef Tokens. The runtime can resolve these tokens for you during runtime using the `Module.ResolveMember()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems to be what I am looking for.  However, it seems to be part of mscorlib.dll and this library is not loaded in the exe. I tried to load it via the debugger but it seems to include other dll dependencies that makes it impossible to do ...

Comment: Afaik mscorlib or its dotnet core equivalent should always be present. It contains the most basic types. You can lookup a metadata token manually, please consult the ecma-335 standard document to learn more about the metadata table layout and construction.

Comment: I am currently using frida and I am calling already loaded libraries. If there was a low level equivalent in clr.dll or clrjit, that would be great for me. I will try to load mscorlib.dll and see of it works this way. The other alternative I have is to rewrite everything I did so far with a CS app to be able to use this function.

Comment: Have a look at the reference source https://referencesource.microsoft.com and dig into `Module.ResolveMember`. All internal resolve methods are implemented in unmanaged code. Eg. `private extern static RuntimeMethodHandleInternal ResolveMethod([...])`. Maybe they are actually from clr.dll.

Comment: Indeed, I can see this in clr.dll : MethodDesc *QCALLTYPE ModuleHandle::ResolveMethod(QCall::ModuleHandle  [...] . There is also maybe ModuleHandle::ResolveField but they seem hard to use. I was not able to understand how to fill arguments during runtime... I tried without success to load mscorlib.dll via frida.

Comment: I found it : CEEINFO:ResolveToken ;)

Comment: Glad you found something. You could provide an short answer to you own question below. It will provide guidance for someone searching the same thing.